# Import multiple .dta files, remove haven labelled fomat, create a dataframe from all imported dta files in R

Tags: r

I am trying to import multiple .dta files and create a dataframe from all imported dta files. I try using the following code but it didn't work. It works for csv files, but I don't have stata to save the plus 100 files I am trying to import and get into a dataframe.

```
library(tidyverse)
library(haven)

tbl1 <-
list.files(pattern = "*.dta") %>%
map_df(~read_dta(.))
```

```r
Error: Can't convert from `$a1` <labelled<double>> to `$a1` <labelled<double>> due to loss of precision.
* Locations: 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, ...
Values are labelled in `$a1` but not in `$a1`.
```

```r
idstd    id preference rotation       a0     a1     a1a      a2     a3a     a3b
   <dbl> <dbl>      <dbl>    <dbl> <dbl+lb> <dbl+> <dbl+l> <dbl+l> <dbl+l> <dbl+l>
1 590217     1          2        1 1 [Manu~     17 2 [Amh~ 1 [Add~ 1 [Add~ 1 [Yes]
2 590218     3          1        1 1 [Manu~     17 2 [Amh~ 1 [Add~ 1 [Add~ 1 [Yes]
3 590219     4          7        2 1 [Manu~     17 2 [Amh~ 1 [Add~ 1 [Add~ 1 [Yes]
4 590220     6          6        2 1 [Manu~     17 2 [Amh~ 1 [Add~ 1 [Add~ 1 [Yes]
5 590221    10          4        2 2 [Reta~     17 2 [Amh~ 1 [Add~ 1 [Add~ 1 [Yes]
6 590222    12         12        3 1 [Manu~     17 2 [Amh~ 1 [Add~ 1 [Add~ 1 [Yes]
```

Answer (score 0):

The following worked for me with a few mock .dtas, but it's hard to be sure without looking at your data.

One suggestion is to use `read.dta13` instead since it handles newer versions (13+) of Stata.

```
library(tidyverse)
library(readstata13)

df_list < lapply(list.files(pattern="*.dta"), read.dta13)
tbl1 <- do.call(rbind.data.frame, df_list)
```

Comment: Hi! Thanks for taking a look. I have added a snippet of one of the datasets. I ran the code you suggested but I got this errors: 
``` r
> df_list <- lapply(list.files(pattern="*.dta"), read.dta13)
There were 50 or more warnings (use warnings() to see the first 50)
> tbl1 <- do.call(rbind.data.frame, df_list)
Error in (function (..., deparse.level = 1, make.row.names = TRUE, stringsAsFactors = default.stringsAsFactors(),  : 
  numbers of columns of arguments do not match
```

Comment: I think the problem is that variables in stata are double labelled. Is there a way to fix this? I am guessing this will work if variables were only labelled as characters, factors, numeric, etc.

Comment: Hi @DSan, I'm not sure about variables being double labelled, but maybe you could share the error you got when trying this? Did it break when doing `rbind` or in the `read.dta13` part?

Comment: Yes, after I run tbl1 <- do.call(rbind.data.frame, df_list)
Error in (function (..., deparse.level = 1, make.row.names = TRUE, stringsAsFactors = default.stringsAsFactors(),  : numbers of columns of arguments do not match